# when is static Database? _db; not null?

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I am creating a database for the first time using `sqflite`. I'm just confused about the creating of dbHelper. all implementations almost are in the same way. the confusing question is `_db` at the beginning of every single opening the application it will be always null, which means that this always creates a new table. when `_db` will be not null?

**the code is:**

```
class DatabaseHelper {
  DatabaseHelper._();
  static final DatabaseHelper _instance = DatabaseHelper._();
  factory DatabaseHelper() => _instance;
  static Database? _db;

  Future<Database?> createDB() async {
    if (_db != null) return _db;
    String path = await getDatabasesPath();
    _db = await openDatabase(
      join(path, "todo.db"),version: 1,
      onCreate: (Database database, int version)async {
        await database.execute('');
      },
    );
    return _db;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR; **the callback passed to onCreate parameter in openDatabase will only be invoked if the the database file wasn't found in the specified path.**

---

if I got your question right, you're concerned about creating the same tables multiple times, is that right?
that won't happen unless user cleared app data. from the [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/sqflite/latest/sqflite/openDatabase.html):

> onCreate is called if the database did not exist prior to calling openDatabase. You can use the opportunity to create the required tables in the database according to your schema

I'll try to map out the scenario of which the events will occur hopping that this will clear everything for you:

*the first time you run your app:*

1. you initiate get an instance of the singelton `DatabaseHelper` through the factory
2. you call `createDB()` to get an instance of sqflite.Database
3. `_db` **will be null**, so a new instance of Database gets created and assigned to `_db` when `openDatabase` gets invoked
4. due to the fact that there's no database file at the path you provide by `getDatabasesPath()`, `onCreate` will be invoked and your tables will be created
5. anytime you call `creatDB()` afterward will not trigger the same workflow because `_db` is not null anymore (because it's static variable)

*second time you run app:*

1. you initiate get an instance of the singelton `DatabaseHelper` through the factory
2. you call `createDB()` to get an instance of sqflite.Database
3. `_db` **will be null**, so a new instance of Database gets created and assigned to `_db` when `openDatabase` gets invoked
4. and because a database file **exists** at the path you provide by `getDatabasesPath()`, thus `onCreate()` will **not** be invoked another time
5. anytime you call `creatDB()` afterward will not trigger the same workflow because `_db` is not null anymore (because it's static variable)